# Как передать агрумент в функцию чтоб он не перезаписывался?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача простая. У меня есть таблица которая в свою очередь отрисовывается JS кодом. Во время вставки элемента в таблицу я сначала всей строке присваиваю функцию, ну типа нажал на строку и можно редактировать. Для начала просто дебажу и тут проблема, она у меня постояно перезаписывается и в итоге у всех функция последнее значение. Как мне навсегда оставить каждой строке неизменное значение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Grundy Заголовок дубликата может ввести в заблуждение, поэтому стоит еще добавить, что в данном случае дело вовсе не в асинхронщине, а в разнице между `var` и `let`. :)

Comment: я если честно в дубликате пересмотрел и попробывал пару вариантов...не работает

Comment: @Yaant, разница именно в асинхронщине: функция создаваемая внутри цикла не выполняется сразу, а выполняется _асинхронно_

Comment: да, но оно всегда перезаписывает значения...я пытался сделать как в дубликате..и нифига не выходит

Comment: @Grundy А, соглашусь. :) Смутило, что в дубликате эта функция в цикле же и вызывается, а тут нет. :)

Comment: @FX_Sektor, тогда надо смотреть как именно ты пытался :-)

Comment: @FX_Sektor А замените `var qqq = ...` на `let qqq = ...`. Правда, в IE это не поможет, но по крайне мере должно подтолкнуть в нужную сторону.

Comment: Обновил ответ. ПР

Comment: @Yaant, в дубликате, кстати, вызывается setTimeout, а не функция :-)

Comment: @Grundy `setTimeout` - это тоже функция! :)

Comment: @Yaant, но не та, которая создается :)

Comment: @Grundy Это уже детали. :)

Comment: Никого не смущает строчка `var obj = $.parseJSON(data);` в обработчике `$.getJSON`?

Comment: $.getJSON это асинхронный метод к контроллеру...он всего лишь вернет обект но не десериализует его...дальше я его десиарилизую в методе $.parseJSON(data)...иначе он будет сплошной большой строкой...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
///копируеш его
const arg = Object.assign({}, source) //source то откуда копируем;
//передаем 
func(arg);
```

Если правильно понял то вы хотите что то типа такова

```
   fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
.then(response => {
    return response.json();
}).then(json => { 
    const N = json.data;
    const table = document.getElementById('table');
    for (const Q of N) {
        let row = document.createElement('tr');
        row.innerHTML = `${Q.first_name} ${Q.last_name}`;
        row.id = `${Q.id}`;
        row.onclick = (event) => {
            alert(`Вы выбрали id = ${Q.id}`);
        }
        table.append(row);
    }
})
```

Comment: Попробывал вот так. http://prntscr.com/lhtsf6  но тогда в алерт приходит с [Object; object] я пыталс десериализовать его методом pareseJSON не прокатило..та он наверно и не джейсон. Пробывал простое значение передать стринговое...но тоже самое

Comment: у меня сейчас вот так на выходе. http://prntscr.com/lhurr4    А хочу что б на выходе было вот так <tr id="trСтаніслав0" onclick="function(obj[0].Id)"> <tr id="trСтаніслав1" onclick="function(obj[0].Id)"> <tr id="trОлег2" onclick="function(obj[0].Id)">    агрменты в функцию я наглядно тут поставил. Туда должны передаваться содержимое своей строки. Просто добавить каждой строке функцию в которую передается содержимое своей жи строки

Comment: ну тогда мой варинт вам подходит

Comment: у вас onclick="function(obj[0].Id)" где добавляется?

Comment: Я его хотел добавить в цикле...как на картинке в самом начале публикации вопроса. Но он начал постояно перезаписываь инфу и в итоге функция всюда передавала последнее значение

Comment: Ну прогрес с вашей помощью есть http://prntscr.com/lhv487    Буду дальше дебажить..как закончу полность - отпишусь и ответ помечу правильно....ксати и когда еще уменьшилось в разы

Comment: я не правильно код написал. я исправил  он рабочий